# How to get all custom claims of Firebase auth user

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get all custom claims of the firebase auth user (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

I'm asking because if I set or modify a custom claim, it removes all other custom claims I set prior to it, so I need to pass all existing claims when updating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the claims via the [`userRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.userrecord) object and its `customClaims` property. For example:

```
  const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUser("...userId...");
  console.log(userRecord.customClaims);
```